# php else to open link

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to open link instead of `return $error;` on below code:

```
else {
    $error->add( 'sms_code_enter', sprintf( __( '<strong>Cont creat dar nevalidat. <a href="#" class="sms-code-field">Click Aici</a> pentru a introduce codul primit pe telefon.</strong>', 'wedevs' ) ) );
    return $error;
}
```

I tried with this code but it does nothing:

```
else {
    $error->add( 'sms_code_enter', sprintf( __( '<strong>Cont creat dar nevalidat. <a href="#" class="sms-code-field">Click Aici</a> pentru a introduce codul primit pe telefon.</strong>', 'wedevs' ) ) );
    header('Location: http://destination.com');
}
```

Comment: Put an `exit;` after the `header()` function

Comment: It as no effect.

Comment: _It as no effect..._ Maybe your code never goes through the `else`? Otherwise it doesnt make any sense (with the given informatoin)

Comment: It does with the mentioned default error action , I need to change that with open link.

Comment: uncomment the `$error->add(...)`and see what happens... maybe it already sens a header

Comment: I tried to replace all code with  header('Location: http://destination.com'); but nothing, the page just showing loading without opening the link.

Comment: Turn on your `error_reporting()`

Comment: `else {
    header('Location: http://destination.com');
    exit();
}`

try this

Comment: did you read my very first comment and OPs answer to that? @Sree

Comment: @B001ᛦ I mean remove $error->add() and try once

Comment: He tried without an exit :)

Comment: try: `header('Location: /');` (does url = your site url)?

Comment: None of the above solutions is working.

Comment: @mario - is it an external url or is http://destination.com on your site?

Comment: Internal url, I just need to load the same website mysite.com/login, that's all. Do you have skype ?

Comment: @mario you want to use relative paths, e.g. if I have a file here: `app/templates/login.php` I'd use `header('Location: /app/templates/login.php')` - if I've used .htaccess to change /app/templates/login.php -> login.php I'd use `header('Location: /login.php')`